# PHP Regular Expressions Counting starting consonants in a string

Tags: php, regex

I need to find out how many starting consonants a word has. The number is used later in the program.
The code below does work, I am wondering if it is possible to do this with a regular expression.

```
$mystring ="SomeStringExample";
$mystring2 =("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzABCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTWVXYZ");
$var = strspn($mystring, $mystring2);
```

Using a regular expression as this

```
$regex= ("^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]");
$var = strspn($mystring, $regex);
```

Does not work as strspn expects two strings.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: I think you mean this, `preg_match_all('~[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]~', $str, $match);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it, using [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
$string ="SomeStringExample";

preg_match('/^[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*/i', $string, $matches);

$count = strlen($matches[0]);
```

The regular expression matches zero or more (`*`) case-insensitive (`/i`) consonants `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` at the beginning (`^`) of the string and stores the matched content in the `$matches` array. Then it's just a matter of getting the length of the matched string using `strlen`. Not the most elegant solution, but I believe it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

this will do. The result of whole regex will be stored in `$matches[0]` and the text matching first capturing parenthesis will be stored in `$matches[1]`, so finding the length of the `$matches[1]` (or even `$matches[0]` since the the capturing is the whole regex) will be equivalent to what your code does. But the performance may not be better

```
$mystring ="SomeStringExample";
$regex= ("/^([b-df-hj-np-tv-z]*)/i");
preg_match_all($regex,$mystring,$matches);
echo sizeof($matches[1]);
```